# Getting negative bounding box while loss is very small

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-dataloader

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hU6o0w0EHVsZRJZXevaa6E5pKiDa9WHm?usp=sharing) is my code in a Google Colab that can be reproduced.

I create a synthetic data set of images with size `200x200` where a rhombus is present. A sample of my data is the following:

[image]

I have a label `x,y, theta, s_x, s_y` where `x,y`s are the coordinates of the center of rhombus, `theta` is the rotation angle of the rhombus, `s_x, s_y` are lengths of its diagonals. I am trying to train a neural network to predict the label of a rhombus. Notice that I cannot use line detector since there are random lines in images. I find the mean and standard deviation of my dataset and normalize the images to train the model. Here is the training loss after two epochs:

[image]

**Problem**

For some reason I get negative number for predicted label which cannot be true. I tried to have a ReLU after the last layer but it did not work.

**Question**

1. How can I train a model that can predict the labels?
2. Is my model wrong?
3. What other models I can use to get it worked?

**Reproducible code**

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hU6o0w0EHVsZRJZXevaa6E5pKiDa9WHm?usp=sharing) is my code in a Google Colab that can be reproduced.

Comment: If you want to get bounding boxes, you should use the object detection model. Faster R-CNN would be good start. You may check this link https://paperswithcode.com/task/object-detection

Comment: @Sunghyun Jun: labels are not bounding box. They are different than bounding box.